# Clustered standard errors, python statsmodels

Tags: statsmodels, clustered-standard-errors

I am trying to understand clustered standard errors better.

I created a very simple example: there are 100 rows, first 30 are from group 0 and next 70 are from group 1. I want to compare estimating the coefficient for group 0 separately, vs estimating it from all the values. I am using following code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from IPython.display import display

np.random.seed(1)
vals = np.random.normal(size=100)
groups= np.array([0]*30+[1]*70)
X =np.column_stack([vals,vals*groups])
Y = np.random.normal(size=100)
mod1 = sm.OLS(Y[:30], X[:30, 0]).fit()
mod2 = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
mod3 = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit(cov_type = "cluster", cov_kwds = {"groups":X[:, 1]}) 
assert np.isclose(mod1.params[0], (mod2.params[0]))
assert np.isclose(mod1.params[0], (mod3.params[0]))
```

I would expect that `mod3` should have the same p-value on first coefficient as the p-value from `mod1`. However, this is not the case. `Mod1` has p-value of first coefficient of  0.757 and `mod3` has p-value of 0.

Am I doing something wrong or simply misunderstanding clustered standard errors? What covariance adjustment should I do to get a model that has the same p-value as `mod1`?

Comment: This is not a good (valid?) case for cluster robust standard errors. cluster robust standard errors assume that the number of groups becomes large. AFAIR, the covariance matrix of the parameters should be singular in this case, but I have not looked at the details in some time. (cluster robust allows for arbitrary within cluster correlation and we need many groups/clusters to estimate those reliably)

Comment: your X variables are correlated. In general, neither parameters nor inference will be the same when dropping a variable, independent of which robust or nonrobust standard errors are used.